# Separate property pages for Visual C++ 2010 / 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 installed on my PC. It turns out that when property page Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user is changed in Visual Studio 2010 the same changes propagate to Visual Studio 2012. It work the other way around to - changes from VS 2012 propagate to VS 2010. This makes it difficult to use 3rd party libs when binaries for different version of VS are named the same, because both VS 2010 and 2012 would be searching the same folder for lib files.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't know if there's a question here or not though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property page, you could (and imo should) create one or more project specific property pages, containing the thirdparty lib information. This has several implications:

**pros:**

1. It fixes your problem, since you can use different property pages for VS10 and VS11 projects
2. You can distribute your projects to other VS environments and other developers more easily, if the project specific property pages are located with the project and not in some general place.
3. Only the projects that need lib X use lib X, as compared to every project uses every thirdparty lib you have.
4. You can upgrade a thirdparty lib in one project without having to fear that the upgrade breaks other projects using the same lib.

**cons:**

1. You'll have to create or copy and adjust the property pages for every new project that uses thirdparty libs. If you have a new project every few days, that can be a measurable amount of work. Consider to make a template project with a very general properties page and copy it around for every new mini-project.

On my projects, I use different sets of property pages per project, in the same solution, e.g. for unit test projects linking to the unit test framework and so on.

Comment: looks like that is the only way